# Display Django form fields on the "same line"

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

I would like to display two form fields on the same line and not each one after the other one.

For the moment, I get:

```
Choice a theme :
   . Datasystems
   . Cameroun
```

But I would like to display this form like:

```
Choice a theme:
       . Datasystems                    . Cameroun
```

My **.html file** looks like :

```
{% extends 'Base_Configurations.html' %} 
{% load staticfiles %} 
{% load static %} 
{% block title %}
    <h3> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Choix du thème DatasystemsEC </align> </h3>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <form class="form" method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
        <br></br>
        {{ form }}
        <br></br>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Valider le thème" />
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I have also a **.css file** :

```
.form-fields {
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:50%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;

    }

.form {
    padding-left:8vw;

}

label {
        width: 35%;
        border-radius: 8px; 
        margin-bottom: -20px;
        list-style: none;
}
```

For the moment, I don't find a way to solve my problem. I looked some tutorials or StackOverflow questions but nothing up to now.

Do you have any idea about this handling?

Comment: If you want to work with bootstrap ,then I have a simple solution for you.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi Thank you for your answer. I just found a solution 10 seconds ago. I gonna edit one of the answers. But I would like to listen your solution ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by **Bootstrap** grid system. As suggested in the question, By this there will be two fields on each row.

Try this:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    {% for field in form  %}
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <b>{{ field.label_tag }}</b> - {{ field }} 
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>  
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a bit more complicated because I'm already using bootstrap grid. In my base_template.html, this part is already scripted like this : `<div class="col-md-10"> {% block content %}
                    {% endblock content %}  </div>` And the `block content` is what I put in my question ;)

Comment: @Valentin Try my answer. Outer col-md-10 will include inner col-md-6 accordingly. You don't need to do anything. And if you are already using bootstrap, then it's recommended to use grid system rather than writing CSS on your own.Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will add in my question an edit part with your script result ;) It doesn't display RadioSelectbox inline.

Comment: @Valentin Now I understand your full requirements. For radio select boxes, you might need some extra CSS.

Comment: I apologize if I didn't give all elements. I will play with extra CSS based on your answer ;)

Comment: I replaced `<b>` by `<li>` and I added extra CSS : `.col-sm-9 li {
        display : inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left : 8vw;
    }` It works so thank you

Comment: @Valentin Welcome :)

Comment: I suggest iterating over the visible fields only: {% for field in form.visible_fields %}

Answer (score 4):

dont use {{ form }}, but manually open the form fields.

```
  {% for field in form  %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    <li> {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }} </li> 
  {% endfor %}
```

CSS -

```
li {
    list-style-type: none; 
    display : inline;
    }
```

I think it will work. Let me know if it does.

Comment: I edited your answer and I found a good solution ;) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Inline Crispy form:
2 cols per row.

```
<form method="post" id="id_form" class="mx-auto text-left">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class=" d-block btn btn-lg btn-success mt-4 w-50 mx-auto">
        Save
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates

also if you are using bootstrap you can add the classes that you need in your forms.py

like:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'myfieldclass'}))
```

or:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'myfield': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
        }
```